# Where to configure FAKE to use C# 6 compiler (instead of C# 5) when building?

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild, f#-fake

I am using [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) to automate some building tasks in my project since a while. Recently I installed VS 2015, and used some C# 6 syntax in one of my project. It builds fine in the IDE, however when running my FAKE script it spots the new syntax as error. I assume this is because it uses the old C# 5 compiler.

Where to configure FAKE to use C# 6 compiler (instead of C#5) when building?

...or do we have to configure MSBuild? 
...or do we have to configure FAKE which MSBuild to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install the [`Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers) into any project that is using C# 6.0 features for it to build on machines without the [2015 Build Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) installed.

That package contains the entire Roslyn compiler for C# and VB and it replaces the default core build target in your *.csproj with one that uses that local copy of the compiler instead.

Comment: Thx. My project is under VS 2015 and VS 2015 is installed. Is it normal that FAKE builds with C#5 compiler? Do I still must have the Compilers NuGet package installed?

Comment: So, this is happening to you on a machine that has VS2015 installed? I wouldn't have expected that, to be honest. I've personally only experienced C#6.0-related build problems on a build server, for instance, that didn't have VS2015 or the 2015 build tools installed. But the above mentioned work-around solved that problem quite nicely and without much hassle. Which version of FAKE are you using? I can see that support for MsBuild 14 was added to [FAKE v3.10](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/commit/3feb832feee11a579fbcc17cefb113e1afc21788). Did installing the compiler nupkg make any difference?